# Rails routing and controller modules -namespacing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have trouble creating a module for my controller, and getting my routes to point to that module within the controller.

Getting this error:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant Api::Fb
```

So, this is how my routes are set up:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :fb do
    post :login
    resources :my_lists do
      resources :my_wishes
    end
  end
end
```

In my fb_controller i want to include modules that will give me paths like this:

```
/api/fb/my_lists
```

This is some of my fb_controller:

```
class Api::FbController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:login]

  include MyLists # <-- This is where i want to include the /my_lists
                  # namespace(currently not working, and gives me error 
                  # mentioned above)

  def login
    #loads of logic
  end
end
```

The MyLists.rb file(where i define a module) is in the same directory as the fb_controller.rb.

How can i get the namespacing to point to my module inside of the fb_controller, like /api/fb/my_lists ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The namespace you have set up is looking for a controller class that looks like this

`class Api::Fb::MyListsController`

If you want to have a route that looks like `/api/fb/my_lists` but you want to still use the `FbController` instead of having a `MyListsController` you need to set up your routes to look like this

```
namespace :api do
  scope "/fb" do
    resources :my_lists, :controller => 'fb'
  end
end
```

In my opinion, instead of including a module `MyLists` in your `FbController` seems kind of awkward.

What I would probably do is have a module `FB` with a generic FbController then have `MyListsController < FbController`. Anyway, this is beyond the scope of your question.

The above should answer for your needs.

**EDIT**

From your comments, and my assumptions on what you're trying to do this is a small example:

**config/routes.rb**

```
namespace :api do
  scope "/fb" do
    post "login" => "fb#login"
    # some fb controller specific routes
    resources :my_lists
  end
end
```

**api/fb/fb_controller.rb**

```
class Api::FbController < ApiController
  # some facebook specific logic like authorization and such.
  def login
  end
end
```

**api/fb/my_lists_controller.rb**

```
class Api::MyListsController < Api::FbController
  def create
    # Here the controller should gather the parameters and call the model's create
  end
end
```

Now, if all you want to create a `MyList` Object then you could just do the logic directly to the model. If, on the other hand, you want to handle some more logic you'd want to put that logic in a Service Object that handles the creation of a MyList and its associated Wishes or your `MyList` model. I would probably go for the Service Object though. Do note, the service object should be a class and not a module.

Comment: Thank you! If i do like you suggest, will the route point to my module included in the FbController? What i want is basically just a main module and nest the "sub-modules" in a way that matches the routes. The fb controller lets you edit/create lists, which contain many wishes. So i would want the lists_controller to be a sub-module of fb_controller, and wishes_controller to be a sub-module of the lists-controller. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think you have controllers and modules confused. I'll update my answer with an example of how I would handle what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you wish to accomplish by including using mixins in your controller. Is it to add methods that your controller can use to create the MyLists and Wishes or will the modules have actions that you wish the FbController to have?

Comment: I guess i did not understand what mixins was for. What i wanted was to extend my fb_controller for the nested resources, like you suggested in your new edit. I was just not sure what the right question was. Thank you btw! Your solution worked, i just had to add Api:: after the <, in your example, like this: class Api::MyListsController < Api::FbController

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. I forgot to add that. Always maintain namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `Fb` isn't a namespace, it's a controller. The namespace call is forcing your app to look for a `Fb` module that doesn't exist. Try setting up your routes like this:

```
namespace :api do
  resource :fb do
    post :login
    resources :my_lists do
      resources :my_wishes
    end
  end
end
```

You can optionally define a new base controller for the API namespace:

```
# app/controllers/api/base_controller.rb
class Api::BaseController < ApplicationController
end
```

If you do so, your other controllers can inherit from this:

```
# app/controllers/api/fb_controller.rb
class Api::FbController < Api::BaseController
end
```

Running `rake routes` should give you an idea of how your other controllers are laid out. Just a warning - it's generally not recommended to have resources nested more than 1 deep (you're going to end up with complex paths like `edit_api_fb_my_list_my_wish_path`). If you can architect this in a simpler way, you'll probably have an easier time of this.

Comment: Thank you! If i follow your suggestion, how should i add my my_lists_controller/module? Should i add it like this: class Api::FbController::MyWishes?, or can i just include a module inside of FbController that's called MyWishes?