# ArgumentError: Ajax::Pacientes#obtener_datos_paciente is not a supported controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using recycled code from a project but in this version I am not having good results.

I use Rails 5.2.2 and RVM Ruby 2.7.1

I need to use this function to call an ajax and deliver the already stored data of a client and fill out a form, the data will be searched through the RUN of each client

I don't understand why the match () are not working for me

Controller Pacientes

```
class Ajax::PacientesController < ApplicationController

layout nil

def obtener_datos_paciente
    #usuario = params[:rut]
    usuario = Usuario.first :rut => params[:rut]
    
    puts usuario.inspect.yellow 

    if usuario.nil?
        render :json => {
            :exito      => true,
            :mensaje    => "No existen registros asociados al rut #{params[:rut]}."
        }
    else 

        render :json => {
            :exito      => true,
            :es_empresa => true,
            :mensaje => "El paciente con rut #{params[:rut]} ya existe.",
            :data => {
                :id                     => usuario.id,
                :rut                    => usuario.rut, 
                :primer_nombre          => usuario.primer_nombre,  
                :segundo_nombre         => usuario.segundo_nombre,
                :apellido_paterno       => usuario.apellido_paterno,
                :apellido_materno       => usuario.apellido_materno, 
                :direccion              => usuario.direccion,
                :ciudad                 => usuario.ciudad,
                :comuna                 => usuario.comuna,
                :telefono               => usuario.telefono,
                :email                  => usuario.email
            }
        }
    end

 rescue Excepciones::DatosNoExistentesError => e
    flash.now[:info] = e.message
    render :json => { :mensaje => e.message }
end

end
```

Routes

```
match(
   "ajax/pacientes/:rut" => "ajax::pacientes#obtener_datos_paciente",
   :as => :obtener_datos_paciente,
   :via => :get
)
```

Controller Usuario

```
require 'json'

class UsuariosController < ApplicationController

helper_method :url_paciente

def index
    @usuarios = Usuario.all
    
end

def ingreso_paciente
     
    
end

def registrar_ingreso
    
end

def ingresar_ficha_kinesica

    alias url_paciente obtener_datos_paciente_ajax_pacientes_path 
end 

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix would be to rename your controller to:
`class PacientesController < ApplicationController` and `match` to `"ajax/pacientes/:rut" => "pacientes#obtener_datos_paciente"`

If your controller must exist in the `Ajax` namespace, then it should probably have a namespaced route as well. An example can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531834/rails-routing-and-controller-modules-namespacing).